# Count the number of selected items in multiselect listbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get the count of selected items in multi select listbox, tried below but couldnt make it work.

```
 var selItem = document.getElementById("users").options; 
        if(selItem.selected == 0){
        alert('select item');
        }
```

here i tried to give alert if there is no item selected, but not working

```
if (document.getElementById('usersb').options:selected.length == 0){
 alert('select item');
 }
```

Can anyone give an idea, how can i do that.

Comment: google you questing and be surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, my friend. Just use the `options[selected]` as the selector

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select')
var options = select.querySelectorAll('option[selected]')
console.log(options.length)
console.log(options)
```

```html
<select name="hullo" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B" selected>B</option>
  <option value="C" selected>C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

Output

```
=> 2
=> NodeList {
  "0": <option value="B" selected>B</option>,
  "1": <option value="C" selected>C</option>,
  "length": 2,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "keys": function keys() { [native code] },
  "values": function values() { [native code] },
  "entries": function entries() { [native code] },
  "forEach": function forEach() { [native code] }
}
```